# MySQL query for total number of cars purchased per month

Tags: mysql

I need a help to find total number of cars purchased based on every month. I have a table(purchase) setup like this (simplified for example):

```
  sno
  country
  purchased_date(yyyy-mm-dd)
  make
  model
```

Now I want to generate a report with the total number of cars purchased every month,
and here's my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(`country`), `model`, `make`, `purchase_date`, `country`
FROM charmy_purchase 
WHERE `country` != '' 
GROUP BY model
```

It produces the wrong report.

Comment: "It produces wrong report." What specifically is wrong with it? Can you give some examples? Why are you grouping by model instead of the month? Your question and your example SQL don't seem to be related.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you want? Your question wording and SQL don't match at all, and it's hard to guess what you want from your question. Why does your SQL refer to the country and model? You don't even mention those fields in your question. It's almost as if the person who wrote the question and the person who wrote the SQL are two completely different people who have never spoken to each other.

Comment: Note that `SELECT COUNT(country)` will not count rows where country is NULL. You might want to consider `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Also I want based on the region. So I used country.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( `country` ) , 
    `model` , 
    MONTH(purchase_date) AS Month
FROM 
    charmy_purchase 
WHERE 
    `country` != '' 
GROUP BY 
   model,
   MONTH(purchase_date)
```

**EDIT**

If you have different years. Then you might consider grouping on year as well. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( `country` ) , 
    `model` , 
    MONTH(purchase_date) AS Month,
    YEAR(purchase_date) AS year
FROM 
    charmy_purchase 
WHERE 
    `country` != '' 
GROUP BY 
   model,
   MONTH(purchase_date),
   YEAR(purchase_date)
```

Useful references:

- [MONTH(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
- [YEAR(date)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If you are fine with the answer. You might consider accepting it?